# Set different languages for different users

Tags: settings, languages, multi-user

I'd like to set different languages per user in my nexus 7 (Android 4.2), but the only option I've found for changing the language is system-wide, and applies to all the users. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Perhaps a Tasker script might work... Hope a Tasker guru responds.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from Android directly. A Google code issue has been opened to ask for this, but the issue has been tagged obsolete. [Google code ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56044).

If you have [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) installed, the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin&hl=en) plugin lets you trigger a system language change.

Ps: Marking as wiki because I don't have enough karma to comment the question.